# How to calculate GenePy score for vcf files in all subdirectories?

Tags: bash

In a parent directory, I have several sub-directories, each of them contain one .vcf.gz file on which analysis should be performed. I want to run following commands on all .vcf.gz files in all subdirectories. What is the best way of doing it?? I am the beginner with shell scripting.

I will add short explanations. The input is .vcf file from every subdirectory. at the end, GenePy score is calculated.

To improve score consistency, filtering step:

```
vcftools --gzvcf GENOTYPED_ALL.vcf.gz --minGQ 20 --recode --out GENO_FILT_GQ20 # Set GQ<20 as missing ( retain high confidence calls)
vcftools --vcf GENO_FILT_GQ20.vcf --max-missing 0.7 --out filtered # Remove SNVs with missing rate >30%
vcftools --vcf filtered.recode.vcf --min-alleles 2 --max-alleles 2 # Keep only Biallelic SNVs
```

Make annovar-ready file:

```
./annovar/convert2annovar.pl \
    -format vcf4 FINAL_GQ20M30_BIALL.recode.vcf.gz \
    -outfile ALL_genepy.input \
    -allsample \
    -withfreq \
    -include 2>annovar.log
```

Annotate against refGene,gnomad_exome,cadd13,eigen,revel,gwava,dann using Annovar

```
./annovar/table_annovar.pl \
        ALL_genepy.input \
        ./annovar/humandb/ \
        -buildver hg19 \
        -out ALL_genepy \
        -remove \
        -protocol refGene,gnomad_exome,cadd13,eigen,revel,gwava,dann \
        -operation g,f,f,f,f,f,f \
        --thread 40 \
        --maxgenethread 40 \
        -nastring . >>annovar.log
```

Combine Genotypes and annotations

```
cut -f 18- ALL_genepy.input > a1
zgrep '^#CHR' FINAL_GQ20M30_BIALL.recode.vcf.gz | cut -f 10- > b1
cat b1 a1 > ALL_temp
paste ALL_genepy.hg19_multianno.txt ALL_temp > ALL_genepy.meta
rm a1 b1 ALL_temp
```

Prepare output folders/dependecies, making new folders in a current directory to store raw GenePy score files

```
mkdir CADD13_RawScore Eigen GWAVA_region_score GWAVA_tss_score dann REVEL
```

Take the header from the ALL_genepy.meta file and stores it in a newly created header file

```
grep "^Chr" ALL_genepy.meta> header
```

Compute GenePy scores

Once the ALL_genepy.meta file is created, GenePy_1.2.sh can be run by simply iterating through the list of deisred genes. The make_scores_mat_5.py file is in the same directory of GenePy_1.2.sh (every subdirectory)

```
chmod +x GENEPY_1.2.sh
while read gene; do
  sh GENEPY_1.2.sh $gene
done < gene.list
```

This is code that I have run for .vcf files when I had only one .vcf file. Now, I have over 200 subdirectories, in each there is one .vcf file for analysis.

How to wrap up this code to be executable for all subdirectories at once?

I tried with the folowing code. But **the result file is not saved in the corresponding subdirectory**. It is saved in main directory, and every time it got overwritten with next one.

```
    find . -type f -name '*.vcf'      \
   -exec vcftools --gzvcf {} --minGQ 20 --recode --out GENO_FILT_GQ20 ';'   \
   -exec vcftools --vcf GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf --max-missing 0.7 --out filtered  ';'\
   -exec vcftools --vcf GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf --min-alleles 2 --max-alleles 2  ';'\
   -exec /home/bioinformatics/Dokumente/pipeline_test/annovar/convert2annovar.pl \
    -format vcf4 GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf \
    -outfile ALL_genepy.input \
    -allsample \
    -withfreq \
    -include 2>annovar.log ';'\
   -exec /home/bioinformatics/Dokumente/pipeline_test/annovar/table_annovar.pl \
        ALL_genepy.input \
        /home/bioinformatics/Dokumente/pipeline_test/annovar/humandb/ \
        -buildver hg19 \
        -out ALL_genepy \
        -remove \
        -protocol refGene,gnomad_exome,cadd13,eigen,revel,gwava,dann \
        -operation g,f,f,f,f,f,f \
        --thread 40 \
        --maxgenethread 40 \
        -nastring . >>annovar.log';'\
    -exec cut -f 18- ALL_genepy.input > a1';'\
    -exec zgrep '^#CHR' GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf | cut -f 10- > b1';'\
    -exec cat b1 a1 > ALL_temp';'\
    -exec paste ALL_genepy.hg19_multianno.txt ALL_temp > ALL_genepy.meta';'\
    -exec rm a1 b1 ALL_temp #remove';'\
    -exec mkdir CADD13_RawScore Eigen GWAVA_region_score GWAVA_tss_score dann REVEL ';'\
    -exec grep "^Chr" ALL_genepy.meta> header ';'\
    -exec chmod +x GENEPY_1.2.sh ';'\
    -exec while read gene; do
  sh GENEPY_1.2.sh $gene
done < gene.list ';'\
done
```

Thank you for all suggestion, I appreciate it.

Comment: btw, I would reccomend not using vcftools and switch to using bcftools, since I believe that vcftools isn't under active development any more and may therefore contain bugs of some kind.